# Let be the function: $f(x,y):=\ln \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

Let's calculate $f''_{xx}+f''_{yy}$ I get for $f'_{x}=\frac{x-1}{x^2-2x+y^2+2y+2}$ and for $f'_{y}=\frac{y+1}{x^2-2x+y^2+2y+2}$ Are my calculations correct? How can I continue it?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Now derive using the quotient rule.

Comment: this function is harmonic.

Comment: for $f''_{xx}=\frac{2x-x^2+y^2+2y}{x^2-2x+y^2+2y+2}^2$, is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your first derivative we have:
$$
f_{xx}+f_{yy}=\frac{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2-(x-1)(2x-2)+(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2-(y+1)(2y+2)}{[(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2]^2}=
$$
$$
=\frac{2(x-1)^2+2(y+1)^2-2(x-1)(x-1)-2(y+1)(y+1)}{[(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2]^2}=0
$$

and this shows that the function $f$ is armonic as suggested by Surb.